# How do you make Rails provide access to an EXISTING database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

All of the Rails tutorials I've looked at seem to revolve around creating a new database and then making the contents of the database accessible through the web page.  You get access to the user list after you enter the following commands:

```
    rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
    rake db:create:all
    rake db:migrate
```

But what if you already created the user database with data in it?  What is the alternative procedure for providing access to the user database?

UPDATE 1: I'm using a Postgres database.

Comment: The URL, of course, is http://localhost:3000/users .  I wasn't allowed to post the URL in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

For migrating all the data you'll have to use an external tool, depending on your database type.

Or you can export all the data to JSON and then import it, which could be done relatively easy, since Ruby can easily import and export JSON.

You can export your current data to JSON, directly by running a native SQL query selecting the users data and then converting it to JSON.

Comment: What external tools are available for migrating data?  Are there any tutorials or other exercises that provide examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you looking for

If u want to use database of your choice from postgres you need to specify its adapter ,dbname,username and password in database.yml

If u want to migrate all ur data from one db to another db u should create a dump of db and restore that dump in another ...

**now steps for dump are**

The idea behind this dump method is to generate a text file with SQL commands

> pg_dump dbname > outfile

**Restoring the Dump**

The text files created by pg_dump are intended to be read in by the psql program. The general command form to restore a dump is

> psql dbname < infile

You can refer

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html

http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/tutorials-quickstarts/all-platforms/how-dump-and-restore-postgres-plus-databases